# How does the EVM connect to all the blockchain nodes?

Tags: evm

Someone recently told me that Ethereum does not use IP addresses to work out the node connections. I know networkid is used in the connection but how does networkid translate into the EVM finding the relevant nodes?

I assume there must be a broadcast mode for a node and TCP/IP is used somehow to sent messages. But if IP addresses are not used, how does the EVM workout the relevant nodes?

Comment: I did some checks and it seems that the enode is used to define a bootnode which then is defined by a static IP address.

Answer (score 1):

The Blockchain network has its own network layer "on top of" TCP/IP and it is a p2p protocol.  Ergo, the Blockchain protocol or ÐΞVp2p (peer-to-peer)
ÐΞVp2p sends messages using RLPx, an encrypted and authenticated transport protocol. ÐΞVp2p nodes communicate in terms of packets No other messages may be sent until a “Hello” is received Encrypted handshake.

When you launch a Blockchain Genesis node/client with Geth for example all nodes no matter what computer they are running on will communicate over the internet but communicating p2p using the DEVp2p